# Angular updating components using services

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I'm new to Angular and I need help sharing data between components and services. My first component(A) is a list of items, once an item is clicked on it passes a UID to a service. When this ID is sent to the service (ProcessId) is updated, I need my second component(B) to make a GET request, retrieve data from my endpoint and render it. I hope I explained this properly.

Component A

```
export class SidebarCardsComponent implements OnInit {
eventData: any;
eventId:number;
eventsUrl = 'URL'

  constructor(private _clientService: ClientService) {}


  ngOnInit() {

     fetch(this.eventsUrl).then(res => res.json())
      .then((data:any) => {
        this.eventData = data;
      });
  }


sendEvent(eventId){
  this._clientService.receiveEvent(eventId);
  }
}
```

MY SERVICE

```
 processId: number;

 receiveEvent(eventId){
   this.processId = eventId;
   console.log(this.processId)
 }
```

Comment: Check how `Observable` works: https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: The documentation lays out some common component interaction patterns: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction